# Comment Section for Column limited in MySQL

Tags: mysql, comments, alter-table

If I try to type more characters into the comment section of a column within my MySQL Database it says

```
No Changes detected
```

It seems I can only store 1063 characters in a comment

Is there a way I can extend the length of characters for a comment of a column?
I did not find anything for doing that....

Comment: Dare we ask...?

Comment: Comment is supposed to just specify usecase and constraints; why do you need more than 1024 char?

Comment: It's great that you want to be so thorough in documenting your MySQL database, but you should be able to do it by writing more concisely. If you still can't describe the uses of a single column in 1KB, then you need to document the use of your database in another format, like a wiki.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  CREATE TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)

> **COMMENT**
>
> A comment for a column can be specified with the COMMENT option, up to 1024 characters long.

This is built-in hardcoded limitation which cannot be oversized.